# Why does RQT Graph have limited insight into Turtlebot3?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

###Context

The Turtlebot3 platform is commonly referenced in ROS as an example robotics application. I was excited to learn about how this project was structured internally, and so I have downloaded it (only for ROS 1, not 2) and decided to run the `turtlebot3_fake_node` 3D visualization tool RViz as mentioned in [this guide](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#ros-1-simulation).

---

#### Problem

Once I got launched the simulator nodes, as well as the teleop-key input processes, I launched `rqt_graph` in order to check out how the project is structured in terms of ROS nodes, topics, and subscriptions. However, I discovered that there were only a few nodes and topics visible (where are the sensor topics, etc?). The entire robot behavior is encapsulated within the fake node.

[image: image description]

Is there another way to get introspection on how turtlebot3 works internally without an extensive review of the source code? I unfortunately do not have access to the real robot either.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350101/why-does-rqt-graph-have-limited-insight-into-turtlebot3?/) by [cxrandolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/51046/cxrandolph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
The fake node only publishes to those topics. If you don't start anything else, what topics would expect?

**Comment by [cxrandolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/51046/cxrandolph/) on 2020-04-21**:
@gvdhoorn I was under the impression that nodes within ROS typically represented small execution units. So I was expecting to see a node representing a sensor publishing readings to a sensor topic, which would then be consumed by a node that processed information on this topic (e.g. publishes messages to a ¨motor¨ node or something). Then there would be nodes for controlling motors and things like that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:
I'm not entirely sure how the implementation of *one* specific node -- which is intended to provide a very simple and minimal surrogate of a base robot stack -- would contradict your initial assumption.

Whether or not there are multiple nodes would seem to come down to the design decisions made by the author/developer.

If you're interested in seeing the structure of the entire control system, you'd have to start it all up.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-21**:\

> Why does RQT Graph have limited insight into Turtlebot3?

and pedantically the answer would be: it doesn't, it's actually correctly visualising everything there is.

But that is not actually your question I believe.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
Just came across #q268671, which actually discusses the same question (but phrased differently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would seem to already become clear from the description in the guide you linked (emphasis mine):

> There are **two** development environments to do this, one is using **fake node** and 3D visualization tool RViz and the other is using the 3D robot simulator **Gazebo**.

There are two possible options:

1. use the fake node
2. start a full Gazebo simulation

> The fake node method is suitable for testing with the robot model and movement, but **it can not use sensors**. If you need to test SLAM and Navigation, we recommend using Gazebo, **which can use sensors such as IMU, LDS, and camera in the simulation.**

So the fake node is really very minimal (just `JointState`s and a `Twist` subscriber == basic movement).

If you want sensor topics, you should use the Gazebo simulation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2